# How can I show a users by time of the day report in the desktop version google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, android, desktop

In Google Analytics for Android is possible to have a nice table like this one (and is built-in):

[image: users by time of the day on GA for Android]

It seems however that I'm unable to find the same kind of report in Google Analytics for Browser..

How can I build the same report?

Comment: That does look like a useful report.   I've never seen any like it in GA.   Just to clarify, that is available through the GA App for Android as opposed to the Google analytics website when accessed through your mobile device?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes, is inside the dashboard of my GA App for Android, never tried the browser mobile version of GA tho.. but I think this report would not shown the same on GA web version :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is not possible in the browser-based GA interface. The closest you can get is to make a custom report with `Users` as metric and `Day of Week` followed by `Hour` as dimension drilldowns. But this will only get you data, not the heatmap.

In order to get heatmap, you need to export data into something else. [This article](http://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/google-analytics-heatmap/) has a tutorial on how to do it with Google Spreadsheets and mentions the very same report from mobile GA as you did. IMHO it is the next best thing, as long as Google does not make any updates within browser-based GA reports.